# Unable to query parquet data using Redshift Spectrum

Tags: parquet, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I'm using AWS Redshift Spectrum to query some data being stored in parquet format.
Checking the type in Glue I can see the data is an array of structs. Given that I wanted to unnest this array I found this [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html#unnest) and it worked perfectly fine yesterday using.

```
SELECT JSON_PARSE(LOWER(array_col))
```

I applied json_parse to convert the array into SUPER type and for some reasons it only worked with lowercased strings, hence the lower.

When I ran the query this morning I got the following error

```
ERROR: Spectrum Scan Error Detail: 
error: Spectrum Scan Error code: 15001
context: File ...
```

I checked `svl_s3log` as [per the docs on troubleshooting Spectrum](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-spectrum-troubleshooting.html), but the error isn't appearing there.
I checked for the error code online and it's said to be a mismatch of types for a same column, but when inspecting the parquet file in the partitions (I have only 3 so far) with `parquet-tools` I don't find any difference given the same pair name and level.

Today I tried using `ARRAY(array_col)` to convert the array into super type, but it fails with the error

```
ERROR: Invalid protocol sequence 'P' while in PortalSuspended state.
```

Can anybody shed a light here, please ?

Notes:

1. Not sure whether this is relevant, but I set JSON_SERIALIZATION_ENABLE [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_json_serialization_enable.html) to true.
2. The data is being saved using pyarrow 5.0
3. Using select * from table works just fine, selecting only the column works fine as well.
4. Comparing the schema from yesterday with the one from today, it hasn't changed
5. I intended to apply row ordering along the unnesting. Not sure if this is relevant
6. I need to run the query in Looker

Answer (score 0):

Redshift defaults to lower case for all column names so KEY is being seen as key. But data names in your parquet have upper case names so things aren't matching.  You can enable case sensitive column names by setting the enable_case_sensitive_identifier connection variable to true and quoting all column names that require upper characters. I suspect things will get better if you

```
SET enable_case_sensitive_identifier TO true;
```

and changing KEY to "KEY" in your SQL.

Comment: I simply wrote the query with double quotes but I keep receiving the error Invalid Protocol sequence. Not sure if this is relevant, but I'm using Looker to run the query.

Comment: Yes Looker matters here.  That Protocol error is likely a JDBC driver incompatibility.  Is it possible that you have connected to Redshift with the Postgres configuration?  As for the case sensitive identifier setting, you will need to review Looker's docs for how to enable this.  I'd recommend that you get the queries in question working in a workbench in order to separate Redshift concerns from Looker configuration.

Comment: How do I check for the Redshift with Postgres configuration ?
I ran the queries using DBeaver, but for them to work out I had to remove the ordering (curiously it worked yesterday) and use the lower function. Is that behavior expected ?

Comment: Looker calls the type of connection a "Dialect".  This dialect can be Redshift or Postgres and you should be able to review the configuration of your connection on the "admin panel".  See https://docs.looker.com/setup-and-management/connecting-to-db

Comment: Did you "SET enable_case_sensitive_identifier TO true; " in DBeaver?  This is what is needed to treat json / super keys in a case sensitive manner.  The problem is that all tables and column names are case insensitive in Redshift but the keys in super data are often case sensitive.  This means that the SQL interpreter needs to be case sensitive.  Be aware that throwing this switch will make it so that the column "A" and column "a" are different but many BI tools expect that databases are case insensitive.  This could cause errors and BI tools, such as looker, may not have solved this yet.

Comment: I'm using Redshift. And I did set the enable to True and used the double quotes but didn't work. I created a fresh user and by setting the json_serialization_enable to True the whole query worked (ordering included).
What I'm failing to understand is that the user I was using have the same and only setting applied but I receive still the 15001 error

Comment: Ok that error (15001) generally indicates a column (definition) mismatch between the external table definition and the contents of the files in S3.  There may be useful information in svl_s3log system table.  So this seems like a different cause than before.  Now as to how two users can see this definition differently - my first thought is that one is in a transaction with different a different version of the table defined (but this is only a guess).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238664/discussion-between-lucas-abreu-and-bill-weiner).

Comment: Follow up from chat - you say "But select * works just fine" and that the failure with the above SQL fails intermittently with error 15001.  This seems like an important clue.  Does "select array_col from ..." work reliably?  What about "select lower(array_col) from ..."?

Comment: Both commands works reliably. But I believe it's due to ENABLE_SERIALIZATION_ENABLE being set to true

Also I've found that removing the ROW_NUMBER() being made on the query, the error seems to quit, but I don't get the needed results

Comment: I haven't seen the full SQL you are running.  Serialization is going to make columns from your parquet into max varchars.  If your query is creating an implied data type on the source data it could be creating a mismatch.  Do you think you could package up a test case?

Comment: Mind moving it to the chat again ?

Comment: somewhat related I am trying to set `SET enable_case_sensitive_identifier TO true` at a session level in DBeaver but dont know where to add that setting. @LucasAbreu  were you able to set this once so it always applied to the connection in DBeaver or are you setting it every time ? Thanks

Comment: Session level, maybe in dbeaver additional con params. If you're using always the same user, you can maybe add this config to it using `ALTER USER <my_user> SET enable...`
@zayquan